# Old story about a boy who travels across the universe

Tags: story-identification, aliens, time-travel, space, teleportation

This is a story/novel I read a long time ago. I read it around 10-15 years ago, but I believe it was released much earlier than when I read it. The book was quite thick, as thick as or thicker than *Harry Potter: the Half Blood Prince* or *The Order Of the Phoenix*. I'll try my best to remember some of the story:

- The boy's parents live in a space station on the moon. I think his father's job is a mechanic or something to do with spacecrafts.
- The boy found some crystal/mechanical device after a comet/asteroid/UFO passed by.
- The thing that the boy found opened some kind of a gate that sucked the boy through.
- When the boy came out of the gate, he came out of a structure/building; the gate was opened inside the building.
- The boy visited various planets using the gate and tried to get back home.
- In the middle of the story, a girl (alien but human-like?) joined the boy in travel through the gate.
- I think in the end the boy succeed to get back home with the girl. but time has long passed

That's all what I remember about the book, I do not really remember much more because back than I was not paying attention except for the story. I think the background cover is a boy seen in outer space.

Comment: The book is quite thick. As thick as or thicker than Harry potter book I think

Comment: :) Thick as *which* Harry Potter book? They went from pretty normal to doorstopper.

Comment: Half Blood Prince / Order Of Phoenix I think.

Comment: Old story . . . a long time ago . . . ***around 10–15 years ago!?!?!?***

Answer (score 3):

Could be **The Homeward Bounders** by Dianna Wynn Jones.
[Link to wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Homeward_Bounders)
Points that fit:

- The cover does look like a boy on the moon.
- There are gates to enable the boy to move between worlds
- The boy is joined by a girl part way through
- The boy is trying to get home and succeeds but 100 years have passed and he can never get home.

Points that don’t fit:

- The boy lives in a village at the beginning.
- It’s not crystals that start his journey between worlds, it’s scheming god-like creatures. They force the boy to keep moving from world to world.
- It’s a thick book by Diana Wynn Jones standards, but not as thick as OOTP. Maybe 300 pages.
- No UFO.

Comment: Actually the boy, Jaime Hamilton, lived in a big city and his parents owned a grocery story. The book is available on Achieve.org, and you can read it with a free subscription. I would suggest the OP check out the book and see if it matches.